# MySQL Employee Database install

Tags: mysql, installation, wamp, failed-installation

I'm struggling a lot with the installation of this DB. I have looked and tried many different methods of importing but still nothing. I understand this may have been posted before but I cannot find an answer to make this work.

It appears that nothing can see the .DUMP files but there are definitely there;

[What the Temp Directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxnfw.jpg)

I am using a new version of WAMP which I have been able to use to install the **"Sakila DB"**

I have unzipped the full file from https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db to the following directory; C:\temp\test_db-master

I then open the MySQL app with CMD from this location:   `C:\Users\skino>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe" -u root -p`

this then gives me the **MySQL>** prompt

after this I use the following Command to CD to the Directory and load the SQL.

SOURCE C:/temp/test_db-master/employees.sql

and then I get the below... can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong

```
mysql> SOURCE C:/temp/test_db-master/employees.sql
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.91 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Database changed
+-----------------------------+
| INFO                        |
+-----------------------------+
| CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 6 warnings (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+------------------------+
| INFO                   |
+------------------------+
| storage engine: InnoDB |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.56 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+---------------------+
| INFO                |
+---------------------+
| LOADING departments |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_departments.dump', error: 2
+-------------------+
| INFO              |
+-------------------+
| LOADING employees |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_employees.dump', error: 2
+------------------+
| INFO             |
+------------------+
| LOADING dept_emp |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_dept_emp.dump', error: 2
+----------------------+
| INFO                 |
+----------------------+
| LOADING dept_manager |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_dept_manager.dump', error: 2
+----------------+
| INFO           |
+----------------+
| LOADING titles |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_titles.dump', error: 2
+------------------+
| INFO             |
+------------------+
| LOADING salaries |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries1.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries2.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries3.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'show_elapsed.sql', error: 2
mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have installed the version of MYSQL Workbench that also comes with an instance of MYSQL. So now you have 2 MYSQL Servers installed.

You are loading one and then looking for the database in the other.

Uninstall the MYSQL Workbench and the MYSQL Instance that comes with it. This will leave you only the MYSQL that comes with WAMPServer.

Then re-install MYSQL Workbench and do not take the option to install a database server as well.

You can then connect Workbench to the MYSQL that comes with WAMPServer.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. i hadnt thought of that logically had i. 

the other thing i think caused me an issue was i hadnt CD'd into the directory where the SQL file was to begin with. 

all up and running now. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is : Open MySQL workbench. then FILE > RUN SQL SCRIPT select employees.sql file . simple run. 
good luck